# Ambiguous type using parameterized types Haskell

Tags: haskell, parameterized, ambiguous, gadt

I have a pretty straightforward function that takes a parameterized data type and returns the same type:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

class IntegerAsType a where
  value :: a -> Integer

newtype (Num a, IntegerAsType n) => PolyRing a n = PolyRing [a] deriving (Eq) 

normalize :: (Num a, IntegerAsType n) => (PolyRing a n) -> (PolyRing a n)
normalize r@(PolyRing xs) | (genericLength xs) == len = r
                          | ... [other cases]
           where len = (value (undefined :: n))
```

The idea is that normalize will take a PolyRing with a list of any size and then return a new PolyRing with a padded/modded coefficient vector of length n, where n is part of the type of the PolyRing passed in.

I'm getting the error:

```
Ambiguous type variable `a0' in the constraint: 
(IntegerAsType a0) arising from a use of `value'
```

I've looked at all of the other SO posts on this error, and still have nothing. The error occurs even if I remove all references to 'len' (but keep it in the where clause), so the problem is with

```
(value (undefined :: n))
```

which is virtually identical to how I've used IntegerAsType in other places.

While you are at it, I'm also taking suggestions for alternatives to the parameterized type system I'm using now. In particular, it is a pain because I have to define IntegerAsType for lots of different values. We are using the types rather than parameters to ensure, for example, that you can't add two elements of different polynomial rings (the parameter 'a' makes sure you can't add polynomial rings mod the same polynomial but over different underlying rings).

Thanks

Comment: Since `PolyRing` doesn't store a value of type `n` anywhere, the _only_ thing your client code can ever do with `n` is call `value` on an undefined value of that type. So why do you have that type around? Why not just use `data PolyRing a = PolyRing Integer [a]` instead, as if you had already called `value` for the user?

Comment: You should remove the context of the `newtype` declaration.  It serves no purpose and is deprecated.

Comment: @Daniel: The n represents the modulus in the ring. It doesn't make sense to add two elements from different rings, so having the 'n' stick around ensure that we don't. That said, there might be a better way to accomplish the same thing. We would like to have the types checked at compile time vs runtime though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature for `normalize` doesn't create the scope for the type variable `n` in `undefined :: n`.

Try this:

```
normalize r@(PolyRing xs :: PolyRing a n) | ... = ...
          where len = value (undefined :: n)
```

Alternatively,  you can use an explicit `forall` in the type signature for `normalize`:

```
normalize :: forall a n . (Num a, IntegerAsType n) => (PolyRing a n) -> (PolyRing a n)
normalize r@(PolyRing xs) | ... = ...
      where len = value (undefined :: n)
```

See http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.3/html/users_guide/other-type-extensions.html#decl-type-sigs

Comment: Okay, that works...
But please explain why! Since I'm using ScopedTypeVariables, shouldn't the type signature imply the type of the argument?

I would love a good tutorial at this level as well!

Comment: See the link I provided.  A type signature only brings the type variables into the scope if the type variables are explicitly quantified in the signature.   On the other hand, pattern bindings _always_ bring the type variables into the scope

Comment: Your solution is proposed here: http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/haskell-prime/wiki/ScopedTypeVariables

But I thought ScopedTypeVariables would mean I precisely that the signature DOES create the scope for 'n'.

Edit::Thanks for the link (posted this before your edit)