# ScopedTypeVariables are sometimes in scope, sometimes not

Tags: haskell, types, scope, parameterized

I'm trying to figure out when my type parameters will be in scope. I have what appears to me to be two identical examples, but one doesn't work.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
class IntegerAsType a where
  value :: a -> Integer   

class BaseRing a where
  primroot :: a -> Integer -> a

newtype Zq q = Zq Integer deriving (Eq)

instance (IntegerAsType q) => Num (Zq q) where
...
negate (Zq x) = Zq ((value (undefined :: q)) - x) --THIS WORKS

instance (IntegerAsType q) => BaseRing (Zq q) where
primroot = (xyz::(Zq q)) m = (value q)+m --(as an example), DOES NOT WORK
```

What is the difference between these two instantiations (why does one work, and one not work)?

I'm referencing a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7294149/ambiguous-type-using-parameterized-types-haskell), where it was suggested that I put the type in function parameter. That worked previously, but in this case leaving out the explicit type of the argument gets me the same error:

```
Not in scope 'q'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`q` is a type variable, not a regular variable. That's why `value (undefined :: q)` works and `value q` doesn't.

Comment: Let me check this, I"m not sure if it's a typo in my post only, or if it is the main problem...

Comment: There are two `=` signs in that line, is that a typo too?

Comment: Thanks, you are correct! I see what I was doing differently: In some other code, I actually had qx as an argument of type IntegerAsType. I could call 'value' on it, but I can't call value on q itself.